How can I drain washing machine into toilet cistern downpipe?
I've a toilet with separate cistern to bowl, so has a 2" (?) downpipe from the cistern into the bowl.
I would like to setup a washing machine nearby and wondered if I could drain into that downpipe with a tee-connection?  I'm happy that washing-machine suds/water will appear in the bowl.  But I'm concerned that if I flush the cistern, would it force water out into the washing machine?
I can't tap into the soil-pipe as it's clay and I really don't want to disturb it.
Nearest waste-water is two rooms away in the bathroom, so not so easy to get to.

Might be unpleasant to someone sitting on the toilet if the machine starts discharging.  Not saying this is generally a good idea, but specifically on back pressure into the machine, if the hose takes a loop higher than the top of the cistern before joining the downpipe it won't backflow.

It's hard to know if this connection will mess up the draining of the cistern or not.  it largely depends on what flush system it uses.

Where on the planet? It's probably a code violation in most places that apply a plumbing code. It's also extemely likely to eventually (or immediately) lead to an overflowing toilet, as washing machines tend to pump out a lot of water very fast...

Check with the locals to see about a grey water drainage.  A few places allow, most do not, but better than down the toilet if the toilet overflows.

@Ecnerwal   If a toilet outflow becomes blocked by a foreign object, I'd rather be warned of that by overflowing laundry water than by the more usual means!

Why not put the hose straight in the bowl?  It's less ugly, less hacky, fewer things to go wrong, easy to reverse temporarily or permanently, When you do laundry you put the hose in the bowl and cover with a sign.   When you're done you remove it so it doesn't freak out people using the toilet.

Even a wide open toilet is designed for a quick influx of a limited amount of water.

Thank you all!  :)
